# Issues with lists? Error checking not working

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am relatively new to python, and I just started learning how to use classes. This is the first program I've made where I've tried to integrate them, but I'm coming up with a small issue I can't seem to fix, and I think it has to do with lists. The code is as follows:
(The topic is getting the user to choose what type of seat to purchase).

```
class SeatBooking:
    def __init__(self, seat):
        self.seat = seat
        possible_types = []
        possible_types.extend(["Low_Economy", "Standard_Economy", "High_Economy",
                        "Business", "First", "Residence"])
        possible_types = " ".join(possible_types)
        while True:
            if self.seat not in possible_types:
                print("Sorry, but this is not a valid answer. Please try again!")
                self.seat = str(input("What type of ticket would you like? The possible types are: {} "
                            .format(possible_types)))
            else:
                print("You have chosen to book a {} ticket.".format(self.seat))
                confirmation = str(input("Please confirm with 'Yes' or 'No': ")).lower()
                if confirmation == "yes":
                    print("Excellent decision! Ready to continue")
                    print("=" * 170)
                    break
                elif confirmation == "no":
                    self.seat = str(input("What type of ticket would you like? The possible types are: {} "
                                .format(possible_types)))
                else:
                    print("That doesn't seem to be a valid answer.")
```

Here is the main file (to execute the different classes I'll make):

```
import type_seat
# Choose the seat to book
print("=" * 170)
print("Welcome to Etihad! This program can help you organize your       flight, payments and usage of miles!")
possible_types = []
possible_types.extend(["Low_Economy", "Standard_Economy", "High_Economy",
                   "Business", "First", "Residence"])
possible_types = " ".join(possible_types)
seat_type = str(input("What type of ticket would you like? The possible     types are: {}. "
                      .format(possible_types)))

type_seat.SeatBooking(seat_type)
```

The problem I have is that I seem to be able to enter certain letters and it doesn't count them as an error even though they're not one of the available seats. For example, when I enter the letters "h" or "s", my error checking part of the code doesn't respond to it, but when I enter the letter "b" or random words like "try" it does. It doesn't seem to be completely random though, and it seems to only happen with letters or parts of the first 3 'items' in the possible_types[] list. However, I haven't tested this fully. This is why I thought it had something to do with lists, so if anyone knows what's causing this, I'd really appreciate it if they could help me resolve this and perhaps help me from repeating this mistake in the future!

Note, for the lists I am using .join, but I also tried str().

Comment: `h` *is* in your `possible_types`; that's just a string with a sequence of characters, and the character `h` is part of that (in the word `High_Economy`). The sequence `try` is not. Why did you use `" ".join()` to make this one string and not leave it a list?

Comment: Oh my god you're right! I removed it and it worked. I assumed that I had to use .join before str() because I kept getting issues with it but I guess not. Also, I'm not the best ;). Anyway, one question though. Do you have any idea why this line:                                                                                   self.seat = str(input("What type of ticket would you like? The possible types are: {} "
                         .format(possible_types)))                                                               gives me a keyboard interrupt?

Comment: 1) you don't need to call `str()`, in Python 3 `input()` **always** returns a `str`. `input()` requires a console with input support for the user to type their response into; I'm guessing that perhaps you are running this code in an IDE console or similar where there is no input? That could cause an EOF to be raised or a keyboard interrupt. Otherwise, no idea.

Comment: Wait the new version doesn't seem to work for some reason.. never mind. When I try to enter something, nothing works.

Comment: I'm using Pycharm

Comment: [Input in python does not wait for my input in PyCharm](//stackoverflow.com/q/35829176) and [sevenal other posts](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp#q=pycharm+console+input+site:stackoverflow.com) look relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have* a list, you are testing characters against *one long string*:

```
possible_types = " ".join(possible_types)
```

The letters `h` and `s` are in that string (in the words `High_Economy` and `Business`, respectively), but the sequence `try` doesn't appear anywhere in the string.

If you only wanted to allow whole words to match, you'd need to leave `possbile_types` a list, or ideally convert it to a *set* (as sets allow for fast membership testing). You can define the list, no need for `list.extend()` here:

```
possible_types = ["Low_Economy", "Standard_Economy", "High_Economy",
                   "Business", "First", "Residence"]
```

or make it a set by using `{...}`:

```
possible_types = {"Low_Economy", "Standard_Economy", "High_Economy",
                   "Business", "First", "Residence"}
```

Do **not** join this into a string, just test directly against the object:

```
if self.seat not in possible_types:
```

If you still need to show the values to a user in an error message, join the values *then*, or store the `str.join()` result in a different variable for that purpose.

Note that you shouldn't deal with user input validation in the class `__init__` method. Leave user interaction to a separate piece of code, and create instances of your class *after* you validated. That way you can easily swap out user interfaces without having to adjust all your data objects too.

Comment: I edited my post. Could you read what I said and help if possible? Thanks. Still confused. However, your answer set me back on track. I won't use input anymore in classes. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: please use a new question for follow-up issues, I rolled back your edit. That said, you are using `str.lower()` but your list contains strings with uppercase and lowercase letters. `'abc' in ['Abc', 'aBc', 'abC']` is false, because there is no `'abc'` (all lowercase) in that list..

Comment: I still don't understand. I used .lower() after the user input just so that it wasn't case sensitive. However, now I think I'm getting over my head in this. I'd better just learn the subject in more detail before I start trying to code in it! I don't think this small thing merits a new question, but thank you for all your help. Top answer given :).

Answer (score 0):

```
possible_types = " ".join(possible_types)
```

Above statement will create one string as "Low_Economy Standard_Economy High_Economy Business First Residence".

Now you are doing

```
if self.seat not in possible_types:
```

This will check for a particular character in the string present or not. In your case you are finding 'h' which is present and 'try' which isn't.

Your program will work if you remove this statement

```
possible_types = " ".join(possible_types)
```