# Issues with classes

Tags: python, list, class

I am still trying to get used to classes in Python, and since I am on vacation, I have no internet so can't look up any tutorials. Therefore, I'm trying to teach them to myself. I asked a question related to this not long ago and have since almost completely changed my code and shortened large sections of it, but it still seems to have errors. I've tried everything I can think of but it's most likely some simple thing I'm missing. Code and output below:

The program is trying to determine what type of seats people want on the plane.

Class:

```
class SeatBooking:
    def __init__(self, seat):
        self.seat = seat
        possible_types = ["Low_Economy", "Standard_Economy", "High_Economy",
                          "Business", "First", "Residence"]
        while True:
            if self.seat.lower() not in possible_types:
                print("Sorry, but this is not a valid answer. "
                      "Please try again!")
                break
            else:
                continue
```

Main code (to 'call' the classes, or whatever the term is):

```
import type_seat
# Choose the seat to book
print("=" * 170)
print("Welcome to Etihad! This program can help you organize your flight, "
      "payments and usage of miles!")
possible_types = []
possible_types.extend(["Low_Economy", "Standard_Economy", "High_Economy",
                       "Business", "First", "Residence"])
seat_type = input("What type of ticket would you like? The possible types "
                  "are: {}. ".format(possible_types))
type_seat.SeatBooking(seat_type)

print("You have chosen to book a {} ticket.".format(seat_type))
confirmation = input("Please confirm with 'Yes' or 'No': ").lower()
if confirmation == "yes":
    print("Excellent decision! Ready to continue")
    print("=" * 170)
elif confirmation == "no":
    seat_type = str(input("What type of ticket would you like? The "
                          "possible types are: {} ".format(possible_types)))
    type_seat.SeatBooking(seat_type)
else:
    print("That doesn't seem to be a valid answer.")
```

Output (what I input is shown in italic bold):

- Welcome to Etihad! This program can help you organize your flight,                payments and usage of miles!
- What type of ticket would you like? The possible types are: ['Low_Economy', 'Standard_Economy', 'High_Economy', 'Business', 'First', 'Residence']. ***Residence***
- Sorry, but this is not a valid answer. Please try again!
- You have chosen to book a Residence ticket.
- Please confirm with 'Yes' or 'No': ***Yes***
- Excellent decision! Ready to continue

My questions:

1. Why does it still output "Sorry, but this is not a valid answer"?
2. Also, I seem to be able to input anything.

Please feel free to check my 'older' version of this code - it may indicate why it doesn't work. However, that one had problems too. :(

Link: [Issues with lists? Error checking not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199537/issues-with-lists-error-checking-not-working/41199622#41199622)

Comment: If you really want to know, and I've edited it for you, it is very slow and I meant I can't watch video tutorials. I don't learn as well from written ones and they have confused me in regards to classes. That's besides the point, however.

Answer (score 0):

this condition:

```
if self.seat.lower() not in possible_types:
```

you convert the seat to lowercase, however the possible types:

```
possible_types.extend(["Low_Economy", "Standard_Economy",     "High_Economy", "Business", "First", "Residence"])
```

also have uppercase letters, this will clash.

less relevant issues:

insert the data directly in the list when creating:

```
possible_types = ["Low_Economy","Standard_Economy","High_Economy","Business", "First", "Residence"]
```

i don't see why you need to use extend, and i don't see why you declare it twice.

If you let the user type, they can enter anything the like.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
    possible_types = ["Low_Economy", "Standard_Economy", "High_Economy",
                      "Business", "First", "Residence"]
    while True:
        if self.seat.lower() not in possible_types:
```

is never going to work, since the value on the lhs is all lower case and the values on the right-hand-side are mixed case. Probably easiest to make entries in possible_types be lower case as well...

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your example.

- One is already mentioned: You convert the input to lower-case but the list contains mixed-case strings.
- You will loop indefinitly if it's `in` the list because `continue` doesn't break the loop!

Also there are some minor inefficiencies which could be resolved by using other data types:

- `possible_types` is defined in the class and in your code. You could use one variable for both.
- lookups in `list` have an average `O(n)` lookup time, you could use a `set` (or if they don't change a `frozenset`) to have `O(1)` lookup time.

In short I would rewrite it as follows:

```
# List of possible types:
possible_types = ["Low_Economy", "Standard_Economy", "High_Economy", "Business", "First", "Residence"]

class SeatBooking:
    # a set of possible types:
    possible_types = frozenset(seat_type.lower() for seat_type in possible_types)

    def __init__(self, seat):
        # Just check if it's in the possible types otherwise raise an Exception.
        if seat.lower() not in self.possible_types:
            raise ValueError("Sorry, but this is not a valid answer.")
        self.seat = seat

# Use the `while` loop where you expect the `input`:
while True:
    seat_type = input("What type of ticket would you like? The possible types "
                      "are: {}. ".format(possible_types))
    try:
        # Try to create an instance and if it works break out of the loop
        seat = SeatBooking(seat_type)
        break
    except ValueError as exc:
        # Print the string saved in the exception.
        print(exc)
```